# AttributeError: module 'selenium.webdriver' has no attribute 'Chrome' error using ChromeDriver and Chrome through Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

This is the code I am trying to use:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver=webdriver.Chrome()
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/HP/PycharmProjects/vestige_bot/main.py", line 3, in <module>
    driver=webdriver.Chrome()
AttributeError: module 'selenium.webdriver' has no attribute 'Chrome'
```

I am using Pycharm with windows 10, Chrome version 85.
I have downloaded the correct webdriver for my chrome version and selenium through pip.

All my code is in a version called youtube_bot. In it there is a file calles .idea that was there when I created the project older through pycharm, and the selenium module installed through pip. In the selenium folder, I have placed the chromedriver folder containing chromederiver.exe.

What should I change?

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell Selenium where your driver is located in your system.

```
driver=webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
```

With PATH being the location of your webdriver

```
PATH = "C:\YourLocation"
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to first download the chrome (chromium) webdriver from [here](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads), which is **supported** by your installed chrome version:

```
from selenium import webdriver
 
#supply path of chrome webdriver to webdriver method 
path = '/Users/folder/Downloads/chromedriver'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)
```

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
  File "C:/Users/HP/PycharmProjects/vestige_bot/main.py", line 3, in <module>
    driver=webdriver.Chrome()
AttributeError: module 'selenium.webdriver' has no attribute 'Chrome'
```

...indicates that your *python* filename is `main.py`. But **`main`** is a key word and you shouldn't be using it as a file name.

---

### Solution

You can take either of the following steps:

- Rename the file *`main.py`* as **`testmain.py`**
- Delete the file *`main.py`* and create a new file **`testmain.py`** and run the program.